# Accessing a serial port from multiple classes

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the serial port to communicate between an arduino and a c# program. I'm kind of new to c# programming. The program has multiple user control forms. Each one needs to access the serial port to send data. All I need to be able to do is write to the serial port in the main form from each classes.

I understand how to setup and write to the serial port. Here is my Form1 code:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    lightsControl u1;
    fanControl u2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        u1 = new lightsControl();
        u2 = new fanControl();
        u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        u2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM4";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Open();
    }

    private void lightsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        u2.Hide();
        u1.Show();
        controlPanel.Controls.Add(u1);
    }

    private void fansButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        u1.Hide();
        u2.Show();
        controlPanel.Controls.Add(u2);
    }

    private void monitorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        u1.Hide();
        u2.Hide();
    }

     public void sendData(ref string tx1, ref string tx2, ref string tx3)
    {
        serialPort1.WriteLine(tx1);
        serialPort1.WriteLine(tx2);
        serialPort1.WriteLine(tx3);
    }      
}
```

I only have one other class written so far. I'm trying to get the serial communication setup before I continue on the rest. I created the sendData function hoping to be able to access it from another class, but I cant seem to get this working. Im using visual studio 2012.

EDIT: 
Its working now. Here's my Form1 code:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    lightsControl u1;
    fanControl u2;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        u1 = new lightsControl(serialPort);
        u2 = new fanControl();
        u1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        u2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        serialPort.PortName = "COM4";
        serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.Open();
    }
```

Here's my second form code:

```
    private SerialPort port; //declare port
    public lightsControl(SerialPort port)//import serialPort from Form1 to port
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.port = port;
        hideTimer();
        updateTimer.Enabled = true;
        stopButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void WriteToPort(string data)
    {
        this.port.WriteLine(data); //function that writes to serial port
    }
    private void onButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusLabel.Text = "Always On";
        hideTimer();
        switch (light)
        {
            case 0://Light 1
                com = light1Name + "On";
                Tx2 = "a";
                WriteToPort(Tx2);//This is where I need to write to the port
                light1Status = 1;
                light1Reset();
                break;
```

The serial port object is in Form1 and its being passed to the other forms that are being used.

Comment: Any errors. What exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume both your forms are child to a parent form, or maybe your other form is child of your Form1. In which case you can create your SerialPort object in the parent class, and send it to your child's class via its constructor.

Like so:

```
private SerialPort port;
public Form2(SerialPort port)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.port = port;
}

// Use your port object throughout the class now.
public void WriteToPort(string data)
{
    this.port.WriteLine(data);
}
```

You would load your Form2 like this:

```
Form2 form = new Form2(serialPort);
form.Show();
```

Basically you create your SerialPort object high in your programs structure and pass it around via class constructors.

Answer (score 2):

In same time you can connect to serial port by one class only. so you need to create a singleton class and use it in other classes.

```
 public class SerialPortClass
 {
    private SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort() ;

    private SerialPortClass()
    {
       // you can set serialPort setting here
    }

    private static SerialPortClass _instance=new SerialPortClass();
    public static SerialPortClass Instance
    {
      get
      {
          return _instance;
      }
    }


    private void Write()
    {
        _serialPort.Write(.....);
    }
```

Now use it in each class like this:

```
   SerialPortClass.Instance.Write();
```